# electron-forge : Missing dependencies = git and node, but which git can I choose?

Tags: node.js, git, electron, electron-forge

Using Windows 10, program launched on Powershell. Using latest Node v11.4.

Electron-forge asks me to have git and node installed. The thing is which git shall I choose and why doesn't electron-forge launch ?

EDIT : Installing Git-scm such as Mike told me to do worked ! I do not know why they do not precise it in the electron website or in the npm database.

Comment: You can download git here: https://git-scm.com/download/win. Not posting as answer since I'm not too familiar with electron-forge.

Comment: Actually, you are right ! Would have never thought that I'll need to install a non-related-to-Node program ! And it worked ! so yes !

Comment: Great! I've just posted a answer to your question. If its helped, do you mind upvoting and accepting the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download git here: https://git-scm.com/download/win.

In the [electron-forge docs](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge#getting-started) it says:

> Note: Electron Forge requires Node 6 or above, **plus git installed**.

I'm not exactly sure what it needs git for but all I can say is that it's required.